# please give me propper syntax for My SQL password setting

Tags: mysql

please give me the correct syntax for creating a password and user name for My SQL 5.5.24
i had tried the code in SQL console but does not work

```
use mysql
Database changed
mysql> UPDATE user
    -> SET Password-PASSWORD('0988')
    -> WHERE user-'root';
```

an error message saying -refer to the user manual for your version is returned.

Comment: `-` => `=` like this `Password = ... WHERE user='root'`

Comment: Understand that this command is basically just like any SQL `UPDATE` statement.  The only oddity is that you're setting the value of the Password column to the hash returned by the PASSWORD() function.  That's "encrypting" (technically hashing) the password.  All of rest is just like any other SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE user
SET Password=PASSWORD('0988')
WHERE user='root';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL to change the password.

I created one user called

```
username: test 
password: test
```

Now, I am changing the password `test` to `testtest`. Let us see how to change the password

mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();

Result: `test@%`

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'test'@'%' = PASSWORD('testtest');

Result: 0 row(s) affected

Thank you.